# Inversion of control container(Dependency Injection)

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Пытаюсь разобраться в данной теме, нашел кучу документации и видео, но все еще смутно понимаю предназначение контейнеров. Начну немного из далека, хочу чтобы вы меня поправили.

Инверсия управления предполагает такую ситуацию, когда мы хотим выполнить некоторое действие, при котором нам следует выбрать способ выполнения этого действия.

Например у нас есть программа которая считывает с базы данных данные и выводит их. Так вот вывод это действие, способ вывода может быть вывод на консоль, вывод в файл, вывод в облачное хранилище и т.д.

Для этого мы создаем один интерфейс `IOutput`, который имеет один метод `write()`. И в итоге мы имеет разные реализации этого интерфейса как например `ConsoleOutput` : `IOutput`, `DBOutput` : `IOutput` и т.д.

И так же мы имеем класс объект которого при инициализации, или при вызове метода(ведь существует инъекция зависимостей на уровне конструктора, метода, свойства) получает любую реализацию `IOutput`. На данный момент я так понимаю принцип инверсии зависимостей.

Так же видел информацию такую, что `Dependency Injection` это просто один из типов инверсии зависимостей, который выражается в использовании контейнеров, но я не до конца понимаю, что это значит.

Контейнеры решают проблему читаемости кода. Когда у нас при инициализации объекта прописывается куча new зависимостей. По этому эти зависимости мы регистрируем контейнером и потом как например в `Autofac` методом `Resolve<>` получаем нужный объект.

Но я не понимаю как выбирать ситуации, в которых это применимо. Ведь при инициализации объекта в конструкторе мы можем указывать не только эти зависимости, но и какие то вычисляемые в ходе выполнения программы поля. И я вот не понимаю как это согласуется.

В общем как то все запутанно у меня тут написано, надеюсь кто то поймет что я имею ввиду и поправит, что я не правильно понимаю

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте исчерпывающую литературу на эту тему - обрывочные статьи и видео не дадут полную картину этой темы, так как она является довольно сложной. Например есть книга - Марк Симан - Внедрение Зависимостей в .NET. Несмотря на то, что она опирается на C# теория там изложена абстрактно и с примерами из жизни, кроме того, является классической литературой на эту тему. И какое-либо знание C# не требуется для понимания этой книги.

Теперь по теме.

> Так же видел инфу такую, что Dependency Injection это просто один из
>   типов инверсии зависимостей, который выражается в использовании
>   контейнеров(но я не до конца понимаю, что это значит)

Нет, использование идеологии DI ни в коем случае не обязывает использовать какой-либо контейнер. Макр Симан отмечает это как одно из распространенных заблуждений. Для реализации DI вы можете использовать "внедрение для бедных", которое не подразумевает использование контейнера. Но DI - действительно основывается на инверсии зависимостей. Контейнеры DI служат лишь для облегчения реализации DI на проекте. Вы пишете инструкцию контейнеру - что нужно сделать, чтобы создать класс который вам нужен, а контейнер следуя этой инструкции просто выдает вам его.

Чтобы не путаться в понятии DI нужно понимать, что DI - это набор принципов и паттернов проектирования программного обеспечения (или, с позволения сказать, идеология). А какой-либо контейнер внедрения зависимостей - это библиотека или исходный код, то есть не паттерн и не принцип.

Следуя "внедрению для бедных" вам придется создать некий "бутстрапер" в котором вы будете создавать (например через new в C#) кучу экземпляров классов и передавать их в конструкторы других классов для их создания. В случае с контейнером вы будете писать инструкции вида - класс A реализует интерфейс Ainterface, а класс B - Binterface, а контейнер основываясь на этой информации и коде проекта сможет понять например, что если вам нужен объект реализующий интерфейс Binterface, то нужно посмотреть конструктор класса B. Если в нем будет написано, что класс B требует в конструкторе как зависимость тип Ainterface - то его нужно создать и передать туда. Потом контейнер посмотрит какие классы реализуют Ainterface - найдет класс А и создаст его, затем передаст в конструктор класса B и в конце концов вернет вам экземпляр Binterface.

> Инверсия управления предполагает такую ситуацию, когда мы хотим выполнить некоторое действие, при котором нам следует выбрать способ выполнения этого действия

Инверсию зависимостей можно толковать следующим образом - для создания каких-либо частей программы (классов или модулей) вы указываете какие именно зависимости (другие классы или модули) нужны для работы создаваемой части программы. Например, если вы хотите сделать модуль, который отвечает за сохранение данных - то в качестве его зависимости будет выступать класс, который инкапсулирует работу с базой данных. Реализовываться при этом такой подход может с помощью различных паттернов (внедрение через конструктор, через свойства или контекст).

Благодаря такому подходу появляется множество преимуществ, например слабая связанность кода, тестируемость (модульная) и гибкость. В примере о классе, которых сохраняет данные - чтобы заменить работу с бд на работу с json файлам вам понадобится только заменить один класс из зависимости, не меняя главный класс (так как DI настаивает на использовании интерфейсов).